# HTML - HREF creates a new blue line under the image

Tags: html

When adding href to a image I see a blue line created underneath the image. Any idea what its called and how to remove that?

Here is a screenshot of the image.

[image: Blue line under the image]

Here is the html code:

```
<html>

<style>

div{
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   width: 400px;
   height: 300px;
   margin-top: -150px;
   margin-left: -200px;

}

</style>

<div>
  <a href="https://10.10.10.10/zabbix">
  <img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/800/1*clU7swMwpx_-jFxwExcCOg.png" width="190">
  </a>


  <a href="https://10.10.10.10/grafana">
  <img src="https://logodix.com/logo/1736625.png" width="190" >
  </a>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: The CSS answer provided is good, but you could also try removing the whitespace between the elements (so it's `<a...><img..></a>` without newlines)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underline is set on the text-decoration property of the "a" element. So setting it to "none" should disable it:

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Or just remove the whitespace